# Clicking to (+) to add SQL Replication table throws exception

Tags: ravendb, database-replication

Getting the following exception when trying to add a SQL Replication table or when trying to save SQL Replication:

```
Client side exception:
System.NullReferenceException: [Arg_NullReferenceException]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide       sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.20125.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_NullReferenceException
   at Raven.Studio.Models.SqlReplicationSettingsSectionModel.<get_AddTable>b__e()
   at Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.ActionCommand.Execute(Object parameter)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.ExecuteCommand()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be [issue 1002](http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-1002) in the RavenDB issue tracker, which was already fixed in build 2324.  You should use the latest stable build, which is 2330.

In the future, if you encounter a clear bug with RavenDB, especially with an unstable build, please report it directly to [the issue tracking system](http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/).

Of course, if it is your own code that you aren't sure whether or not is the cause of a bug any you are seeking a workaround, then those types of questions are certainly appropriate for StackOverflow.

Thanks.

Comment: Matt, 

It is the the most recent build of Raven DB (2330) I am using and still getting this issue. I have logged a support ticket for this and have also seen that it is here:

http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-1028#tab=History

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Ps it has been working on our test server. However, when I have put it on our production server (the most recent build, same as our test server) it is throwing this exception.

Comment: Are you sure that the client and server are *both* on 2330?

Comment: 100%, I have a screen shot but can't upload it to this. The screen shot shows the Management Studio UI, at the bottom right it shows both the server and client are 2330 and I am still getting the error.

Got email from Ayende informing me that this was UI problem only and can still use SQL Replication. However, I cannot save the replication so cannot use.

T

Comment: Ok, if you have an email from Ayende, I'm sure he will get to the bottom of it.  I don't think there's anything more that can come of this here on StackOverflow.

Comment: except that other folks could then see the answer

Comment: If you have a solution please post it back here, I'm having the same problem with 2330.